# Why can't I create a node with a label?

Tags: neo4j, label, cypher

I run this code to create a node with a label according to http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-create.html

> CREATE (n:Person);

but it says:

> SyntaxException:
>
> ==>
>
> ==> Think we should have better error message here? Help us by sending this query to cypher@neo4j.org.
>
> ==>
>
> ==> Thank you, the Neo4j Team.
>
> ==>
>
> ==> "CREATE (n:Person)"
>
> ```
>              ^
> ```

and there is a pointer exactly below a "P"

Comment: Labels are available in Neo4j 2.0, which version are you using?

Comment: I use Neo4j 1.9.4 Community, so Where can I find the 2.0 one? Thank you

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of the downloads page: http://www.neo4j.org/download

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using an older version 1.9 or less. Labels are supported only from neo4j 2.0 and above. If you want to continue with this version, you can create nodes without labels

CREATE (n);

Else, uninstall this version of neo4j (if you used homebrew, "brew remove neo4j" otherwise "neo4j-installer remove") and install the latest from their website.